# QtCharts add custom axis

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I would need to have custom axis on QtCharts. However, these lines cause crash.

```
chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignCenter);
chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Please, can you provide example how to customize the axis? The intent is to have some specified range and axis title.

```
QtCharts::QValueAxis *axisX = new QtCharts::QValueAxis();
axisX->setRange(0, 3);
axisX->setTitleText("x");
QtCharts::QValueAxis *axisY = new QtCharts::QValueAxis();
axisY->setRange(0, 3);
axisY->setTitleText("y");

QtCharts::QScatterSeries *series0 = new QtCharts::QScatterSeries();
for (uint i=0; i<size; i++)
    series0->append(vector4.at(i), vector6.at(i));

series0->setName("scatter1");
series0->setMarkerShape(QtCharts::QScatterSeries::MarkerShapeRectangle);
series0->setMarkerSize(10.0);

QtCharts::QChart *chart = new QtCharts::QChart();
chart->addSeries(series0);
chart->createDefaultAxes();
//chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignCenter);   CRASH
//chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignCenter);

QtCharts::QChartView *chartView = new QtCharts::QChartView();
chartView->setChart(chart);
chartView->show();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some time I found the solution. It could help to someone.

```
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).back()->setRange(-35, 135);
chart->axes(Qt::Vertical).back()->setRange(-35, 50);
chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).back()->setTitleText("axis x [mm]");
chart->axes(Qt::Vertical).back()->setTitleText("axis y [mm]");
```

Comment: You helped me with my problem! Thanks :D

Comment: I have one caveat to add, tested in 5.15.2: `chart-createDefaultAxes()` does not work if a line series has not been added.  That is, no axes will be created apparently.  This is under the hood of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
  chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Chart centre is not valid place for an axis, I suppose.